# How do I react on user input during reactor.run() in twisted python?

Tags: python, json, twisted

Im currently working on a client/server multi player cardgame solution in python using twisted libraries. Im pretty new to python, and this game actually is a proof of concept to myself, as i just want to show myself, that i can do such stuff. but im stuck ~8 hours on this problem now, and i need some advice.
following lines and the following description should let you know, what im trying to do here:

Description:

- Server ist started
- as soon as the demo client connects, server does some stuff in the background (registering, creating pile of cards for the player)
- the demo client now starts() the cardgame
- remote_start is called and calls function hoststart if its started by certain player (to be implemented)
- the cards from the players pile are sent to the client and print out
- the client should now be able to press a number (number of card), which then should be sent back to the server to print out the number (only printing doesnt make sense, but its the only thing that came to my mind right now :P)

**now here starts the problem:**

- as soon as the reactor.run() is started, it seems as whole script is executed (user registered, game started) and the input at the client is done **after** the whole script is executed. so the sending of the entered number is done, before the number is entered within the input function and therefore returns 0 to the server.

I think this is very complex to explain, so please ask any questions which may come up.
How can i resolve this problem?

Can i somehow make the server wait an amount of seconds so that the client is able to input the Number during that time?
Do i need to open a new connection which allways opens if have to wait for input on the client?

---

client.py:

```
PICK = 0

factory = pb.PBClientFactory()
reactor.connectTCP("localhost", PORT, factory)
def1 = factory.getRootObject()
def1.addCallbacks(got_obj1, err_obj1)
ret = reactor.run()

def got_obj1(obj1):
    def2 = obj1.callRemote("register","User A")
    def2 = obj1.callRemote("start","User A")
    def2.addCallback(show)
    obj1.callRemote("pick",PICK)  # Problem

def show(*var)
    data_string = json.dumps(var)
    decoded = json.loads(data_string)
    for card in decoded[0]:
        print(str(card['name'])
    PICK = Input("Which card do you want to pick?") # Problem
```

server.py:

```
print("Starting server on ", PORT)
rpc = RPCs()
reactor.listenTCP(PORT, pb.PBServerFactory(rpc))
reactor.run()

class RPCs(pb.Root):
     sessions = []
     def remote_pick(self,pick):
         print("picked: ", pick)
     def remote_start(self, username):
         for session in self.sessions :
             if (session.getName() == username):
                 ret = self.hoststart(username)
                 return ret
     def hoststart(self,username):
         pile4client = []
         card4pile {}
         for session in self.sessions:
             if (session.getName() == username):
                 ret = session.showpile(0)
            for card in ret:
                card4pile = { "name" : card.getName()}
                pile4client .append(card4pile)
            return pile4client
class Session():
     piles = []
     def showpile(self, num):
         return self.piles[num]
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `obj1` to `show` and call its `callRemote` in show.  Something like this:

```
def got_obj1(obj1):
   ...
   def2.addCallback(show, obj1)

def show(value, obj1):
   ...
   PICK = Input("Which card do you want to pick?")
   obj1.callRemote("pick",PICK)
```

Comment: please correct self.callRemote, then you have answer.
Thank you alot! :)

Comment: I also fixed parameter order...  `obj1` is second parameter in `show`.